# How to construct a patch if I already know the diff?

Tags: build, diff, patch, nixos, w3m

I'm looking to build this project with patches against a current build on my machine using NixOS: https://github.com/spcmd/w3m

As the project notes, it contains diff files if anyone outside of the supported distro (Arch) wants to build the project for themselves.

Since these diffs are already computed, is there a way to generate patch files without having a copy of the the original source, or if I need the source, without having to compare each file piecewise again?

For instance, something like:

`diff fc.h.diff /path/to/original/fc.h > fc.h.patch`

or even

`git blah fc.h.diff origin/project > fc.h.patch`

Using NixOS 22.11.

I don't want to build the project wholesale so I can at least take advantage of the existing packages on Nixpkgs.

Comment: A patch is equivalent to a diff. So not sure what you're asking for?